# R: is there a way to create a data frame with all possible pairs of 2 column values from an old data frame?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame with header `M`, `L`, that looks like this

```
"M" "L"
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 85
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 95
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 95
0.59 95
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 95
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 105
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 105
0.69 105
0.69 105
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 105
0.71 105
0.71 105
0.71 105
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 85
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 95
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 95
0.59 95
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 95
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 45
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 55
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 65
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 75
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 85
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.65 95
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 35
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 45
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 55
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 65
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 75
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 85
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 95
0.67 105
0.67 105
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 35
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 45
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 55
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 65
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 75
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 85
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 95
0.69 105
0.69 105
0.69 105
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 35
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 45
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 55
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 65
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 75
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 85
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 95
0.71 105
0.71 105
0.71 105
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 35
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 45
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 55
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 65
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 75
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 85
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 95
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.73 105
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 35
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 45
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 55
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 65
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 75
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 85
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 95
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.75 105
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 35
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 45
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 55
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 65
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 75
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 85
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 95
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.8 105
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 35
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 45
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 55
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 65
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 75
0.5 85
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 35
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 45
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 55
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 65
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 75
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.55 85
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 35
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 45
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 55
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 65
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 75
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 85
0.57 95
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 35
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 45
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 55
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 65
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 75
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 85
0.59 95
0.59 95
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 35
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 45
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 55
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 65
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 75
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 85
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.61 95
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 35
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 45
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 55
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 65
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 75
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 85
0.63 95
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 35
0.65 45
```

I want to create a data frame from this one, except every row contains a unique `ML` pair. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can try

```
with(df,expand.grid(unique(M),unique(L)))
```

or a more concise one (thank @akrun's advice)

```
expand.grid(lapply(df, unique))
```

Comment: Yes, that is the perfect base R solution.

Comment: @akrun Thanks! That's much shorter and more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `expand` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%        # To find all unique combination of M & L including those not present in the data
  expand(M, L)

df %>%        # To find only the combination that occur in the data use nesting function
  expand(nesting(M, L))
```